# the navigation bar isn't included or aligned with my header for some reason

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to using css and html. I don't know why the nav part doesn't have the same background and it's not at the same height as the logo.
I'd really appreciate the help!

[image]

```css
body{
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

header{
    background-color: #14597f;
    height: 60px;      
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;   
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
nav a{
    color: #ffff;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 10px;   
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: #ca0ed1 ;
}

.active{
    background-color: #1fb5e9;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="./index.html" >
      <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="200px">
    </a>
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html"> Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html"> Produits</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="shopping-cart" href="./shopping-cart.html" title="Panier">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="count">3</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done is following:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;

}
```

and removed `display: block;` from `nav a`

Hopefully this makes sense and it doesn't need explanation. If yes, tell me, I will explain it to you.

This way, it's fixed. Full code:

```css
body{
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

header{
    background-color: #14597f;
    height: 60px;      
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;

}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;   
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
nav a{
    color: #ffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 10px;   
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: #ca0ed1 ;
}

.active{
    background-color: #1fb5e9;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="./index.html" >
      <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="200px">
    </a>
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html"> Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html"> Produits</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="shopping-cart" href="./shopping-cart.html" title="Panier">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="count">3</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: The flexbox system would have been my answer too. [Here is the resource I typically recommend for people learning it](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: that worked!!!! thx so much, i've spent 2 hours just trying to fix thi....

Answer (score -1):

you can use flex with space between and align item center.

```css
* {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
 }
 
 header{
     background-color: #14597f;
     height: 60px;   
     display: flex; 
     justify-content: space-between;  
     align-items: center;
 }

 nav ul{
     list-style: none;
     text-align: right;   
 }
 nav li{
     display: inline-block;
 }
 nav a{
     color: #ffff;
     display: block;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 10px 10px;   
 }
 nav a:hover{
     background-color: #ca0ed1 ;
 }
 
 .active{
     background-color: #1fb5e9;
     border-radius: 4px;
 
 }
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="./index.html" >
      <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" width="200px">
    </a>
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html"> Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html"> Produits</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="shopping-cart" href="./shopping-cart.html" title="Panier">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="count">3</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```